# How to share a single writable file between pods, in the same directory with a non-sharable file (writable configmap)

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage, configmap

I am trying to mount a shared read/write file in my Kubernetes pods. This file has to be identical in all pods. However, in the same directory I need to have a read-only file that is different for each pod. This is why I can't mount a PVC in the directory and call it a day.

Any idea how I can put a sharable read/write file in the same directory as all other pods, but have another file in that directory that's different per pod?

This idea in simple terms is a read/write configmap which I am aware is non-existent. Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider using symlinks in the folder that contains the read-only and writable file. Have the symlinks point to well-known locations for the read-only and writable file respectively. Mount the PVC and configmap to the symlink targets and that should give you the desired behaviour.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm running the `ln` commands in my lifecycle postStart stage. The initial value of the target files are successfully used in the linked directory, but once the container writes onto the files, the changes don't propagate back to the target. I tried running the `ln` command in through `kubectl exec` and the changes propagate this time. Any idea how I can run this command in the container without having to exec into it manually?

Answer (score 0):

The file that needs to be identical in all the pods I would put in a file storage like s3 amazon, dynamoDB or elasticCache. Depending if the file is a text or not.

The specific file I would store locally. Do you need to persist it if the pod dies?

Comment: The read-only file does not need to persist. It is pod-specific, so if the pod is terminated and recreated, the new pod will create its own.

Comment: My concern is about the file that need to be identical, looks some trouble to make by hand a way to sync them. I would let them in central location.

Comment: Since pods will be writing to this sharable / identical file, it seems like it would be a complicated job to sync them in a remote bucket. Did you have any specific structure in mind?

Comment: how is the file, is a txt file? or a image or something? how many writes are you going to have?

Comment: It's a json file, say each pod will be adding objects like this `{"x": 123, "y": 456}` to a list in the shared json.

Comment: are you in AWS? Go for a dynamoDB database or mongo on premises. Then you can have read/ write control. You store this values in a table.

Comment: Using GKE, can't do on-prem with AWS

Comment: You have no-sql on GKE as well. Not sure about pricing, in AWS is quite cheap. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll try it out